# postgres public schema function aliasing

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am currently running postgres 8.4.4 and I have the need to override calls to functions that reside in the public schema of my database.  For instance in pg_catalog there exists a function

> upper(text)

I have a function placed within the public schema that overrides

> upper(text)

My question comes down to overriding the call to public.upper(text).  That is to say I have to execute the function call like so:

> select public.upper(text);

Whereas I want to be able to call public.upper(text) in this manner:

> select upper(text);

How does one go about doing this?

Comment: I think it's a poor decision to name identically to native functions

Comment: I agree as well Ponies, its something I need to prove a potential issue with default user privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set schema search path and place pg_catalog at the end of your search path. 
See [5.7.3. The Schema Search Path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/ddl-schemas.html) and [5.7.5. The System Catalog Schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/ddl-schemas.html) in Postgres manual.